# Insufficient privilege error with DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, dbms-redefinition

I am trying to partition existing tables without dropping and recreating it using Oracle.

DBMS_REDEFINITION package in my Oracle 10g supporting application

I have have given all the necessary permission to the user as per mentioned in the oracle document.

```
grant CREATE ANY TABLE to DDUSER;
grant ALTER ANY TABLE to DDUSER;
grant DROP ANY TABLE to DDUSER;
grant LOCK ANY TABLE to DDUSER;
grant SELECT ANY TABLE to DDUSER;
grant execute on dbms_redefinition to DDUSER;
```

I am able to execute below procedure

```
begin
Dbms_Redefinition.Can_Redef_Table('DDUSER', 'TABLE');
end;
This throws no error neither any result (Assuming this is as expected)
```

But when I am trying to run

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(
    uname      => 'DDUSER',        
    orig_table => 'TABLE',
    int_table  => 'TABLE_1');
END;
```

I am getting below error:

> Error report:
>   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 50
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 1343
>   ORA-06512: at line 2
>   01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"

Could you please help me, what privilege I am missing here? 
or if there is any idea about which operation is executed in line 50 at package DBMS_REDEFINITION?

Comment: Did you create `TABLE_1` already before you run `DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table`?

Comment: yes, it has been already created.

Comment: Have you had any luck on this one? (i.e. I'm facing the same ...)

Comment: I just discovered that privileges requirements of procedures from DBMS_REDEFINITION package differ between oracle db versions. At version *11.2.0.1* it required a lot of `create any` global grants, while at version *11.2.0.4* is only requires `create` schema-local grants.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Can anyone of you help me to resolve the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
grant DROP ANY INDEX to DDUSER;
grant CREATE ANY INDEX to DDUSER;
```

If the tabls contains an index (most probably that's the case) you have to create new indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But no luck with this also, getting same error.

Comment: I assume then you have to ask Oracle support. They should know which operation is executed in line 50 at package DBMS_REDEFINITION.

Comment: seems fair. Could you please guide me how to reach oracle support in that case. Is there any specific team for that..?

Comment: Go to Oracle Support page and open a "SR". Follow the form.

Answer (score 2):

I have just faced this issue. and I was getting exactly the same error on start_redef_table.

So after searching a lot I gave below privileges to user and it worked.

`grant execute on dbms_redefinition package to myuser`  (You already have)

then

```
grant CREATE ANY TABLE to myuser;

grant  ALTER ANY TABLE to myuser;

grant  DROP ANY TABLE to myuser;

grant LOCK ANY TABLE to myuser;

grant SELECT ANY TABLE to myuser;
```

After giving these privileges start_redef_table is working perfectly.

Comment: Is it safe to give all above system privileges to non-dba users?

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 12c there is additional system privilege 'REDEFINE ANY TABLE'.

This works for me.

```
grant REDEFINE ANY TABLE  to myUser;
grant ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER to myUser;
grant ALTER ANY INDEX to myUser; 
grant ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW to myUser;
grant ALTER ANY SEQUENCE to myUser;
grant ALTER ANY TRIGGER to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY INDEX to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY SEQUENCE to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY TABLE to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY TRIGGER to myUser;
grant CREATE ANY VIEW to myUser;
grant CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW to myUser;
grant CREATE SESSION to myUser;
grant CREATE VIEW to myUser;
grant DROP ANY INDEX to myUser;
grant DROP ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW to myUser;
grant DROP ANY SEQUENCE to myUser;
grant DROP ANY TRIGGER to myUser;
grant DROP ANY VIEW to myUser;
grant EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE to myUser;
grant INSERT ANY TABLE to myUser;
grant MERGE ANY VIEW to myUser;
grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to myUser;
grant SELECT ANY TABLE to myUser;
grant UNDER ANY VIEW to myUser;
grant UPDATE ANY TABLE to myUser;
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you were missing CREATE Materialized View
after adding this I was successful redefining as normal user

for Oracle 12.1 instruction says
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS67511

I think in other versions may be the same

```
grant CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW 
grant CREATE TABLE 
grant EXECUTE on dbms_redefinition
```